# Logon failed, please check your name/password. Zarafa on Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: 12.04, server

i'm trying to configure zarafa (for test) following this guide: http://www.zarafa.com/wiki/index.php/Installing_Zarafa_from_packages  (on ubuntu server 12.04) on a V.M. (VirtualBox)

i have just installed these dependencies: `apt-get install php5-cli php-gettext mktemp gawk xsltproc poppler-utils unzip catdoc libboost-filesystem1.46.1 libboost-system1.46.1 libicu48 w3m python-mysqldb apache2-mpm-prefork libapache2-mod-php5 mysql-server python-support libpython2.7 libcurl3`

but when i try to login to webaccess or webapp (as explained in the guide with the test user) i got this error: "Logon failed, please check your name/password."

how can i resolve this issue??

any help be appreciate!

Comment: Please fix your referential link.

Comment: thank you for reply tuxar! i solved the issue! one key of my keyboard was broken... so was  obvious that i used the wrong password! eheheh  anyway thank you for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your Zarafa is configured with the internal database plugin and not with LDAP.

You can try to change your test user with

***sudo /usr/bin/zarafa-admin -c test -p password -e test@example.com -f "Zarafa Test"***

or create a new one

***sudo /usr/bin/zarafa-admin -c username -P -f "Full name" -e emailaddress***

More info about installation process you can find on http://www.zarafa.com/wiki/index.php/Installation